# Running jar file map reduce without Hdfs

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, reduce

I have bundled a jar from my eclipse project. I would like to pass arguments to the jar. Basically an input file to the jar. I would like to know how to give an input file that is not in Hdfs. I know that's not now hadoop works but this is for testing purposes. Eclipse has the feature for  local files. Is there a way to do this via command line?

Comment: Do you want to launch a local job tracker and use the local file system for job input and output?

Comment: just try file:///input location

Comment: @ChrisWhite Something like that. I am able to give local file input from Eclipse. But if I bundle my project as a jar file and try running the jar on hadoop (giving local file as input). It doesn't work.

Comment: 'running the jar on hadoop' - so you're trying to run this via the hadoop script binary?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes! by using ./hadoop jar <jar-file> <args>

Answer (score 2):

You can run hadoop in 'local' mode by overriding the job tracker and file system properties from the command line:

```
hadoop jar <jar-file> <main-class> -fs local -jt local <other-args..>
```

You need to be using the [GenricOptionsParser](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html) (which is the norm if you're using [ToolRunner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html) to launch your jobs.